# An infinite, recursive zoom on Blender?

Tags: rendering, loop

I've seen this amazing video and, like most people on the comments, am wondering how to achieve this effect... an infinite zoom on smaller and smaller objects with a loop!

[Recursive zoom, Blender Animation](https://youtu.be/Dg55xX0IMBY) on YouTube

Of course I'm not expecting a full on tutorial (although that would be amazing!) but some clues as to where I should start looking... thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well..."theoretically" it is pretty easy. here a very easy case:

1. E.g. add a small cube on a big cube like this:

[image]

2. animate the camera zooming in: (first animation, end frame)

[image]

3. animate again zooming in until you get the pic from 2 again.

Repeat the 2-3 animation.

Ready.

The problems arise in the details, e.g. if the zoom of the camera makes problems e.g. clip start/clip end. But you can animate these values too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an infinite recursive zoom in that example, despite the title.  That's a series of [tracking shots](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/tracking-shot-camera-movement-definition/) that rely on, among other things, using depth of field to hide background changes and shot dissolves.  The best place to start looking is the video itself.   At full speed you can see the camera is moving and not just zooming.  Now go to one of the points near where the scene changes are done.

The camera switches from a straight tracking shot to a technique where tracking is smoothly replaced by zoom and the depth of field is dramatically shortened.  Each time this happens, there is probably a cut from a scene where the new items aren't yet present to one where they are.  The zoom is again replaced by a tracking shot and the depth of field is greatly expanded, but at a much higher rate.

It might even involve switching out assets, mostly by scaling assets during the transition phases.

It's one of the best shots like that I've seen, by the way.  Deserves an upvote on YouTube.